# Extract string before "_" or "." characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to extract string before "_" or "." characters. 
e.g..
My C column can have following values and expected output in E:

```
C                            E
115415.csv                115415
12345_BOI_CEO.csv         12345
```

I have a formula for "_" i.e.

```
IFERROR(LEFT(C10, FIND("_", C10)-1),"")
```

So I want a formula which would extract string before the character mentioned in a single formula and not separate formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you were on the right track. Put one of the following standard formulas in E2,

```
=REPLACE(C2, MIN(FIND(".", C2&"."), FIND("_", C2&"_")), LEN(C2), TEXT(,))
=LEFT(C2, MIN(FIND(".", C2&"."), FIND("_", C2&"_"))-1)
```

Standard formula in F2 as,

```
=MID(C2, IFERROR(FIND("_", C2)+1, 1), FIND(".", C2)-IFERROR(FIND("_", C2)+1, 1))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: min_find_replace]

Comment: Nice, but still returns full cell value from C when it does not contain any "." or "_" while Atul's formula returns empty value. But I guess it does not matter much.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include which behavior you want when neither a `_` or a `.` is found? As you can see, I've intentionally appended these characters onto the string to make sure that the whole string is returned if neither is found. If that isn't what you are looking for then please edit your question to reflect the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: I have to run this formula on a excel sheet that is a output of some processing having standard formats which would contain characters other than . or _ . So there is never a possibility of characters other than these.

Comment: I need another formula where column F would have string between "_" and before ".". I have created a formula as fallows: =RIGHT(LEFT(C11, FIND(".", C11) - 1), LEN(LEFT(C11, FIND(".", C11) - 1)) -FIND("_", LEFT(C11, FIND(".", C11) - 1)) ). but for the second record the F column remains blank as it cannot find "_". eg

C                                       E                       F
115415.csv                  115415                 
12345_BOI_CEO.csv   12345                BOI_CEO

expected output is

Comment: So the first one should return **115415** but should the second return **BOI_CEO** or **BOI** or **CEO**? Proabably have to use the [MID function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-function-230833B1-28E7-4EF8-9286-EBA06A3C29AD) at some point. What part of the [REPLACE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-Function-6ACF209B-01B7-4078-B4B8-E0A4EF67D181) is giving you a hard time?

Comment: Expected Output:
F
115415
BOI_CEO

Comment: Added a second formula for column F.

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
=MID(C2,1,MIN(SEARCH(".",C2&"."),SEARCH("_",C2&"_"))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to do this once, we could use the ***Text to Columns*** menu option twice.

First split by *`_`*(underscore), then again by *`.`*(dot). See below for the first step.

[image]

Comment: The questions asks for a formula,

Comment: @TimWilkinson thank you, I noticed that. Provided this solution for completeness.